# How to setup error checking for arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using HTML agility pack and parsing to an array.

The information I am parsing changes and when it changes below a certain level I get unhandled exceptions because I am trying to bind the an element [][] that isn't there.

How would I setup error checking to make sure if the array isn't there it wouldn't throw an Unhandled expection?

Eg... If I use the below code and there is no [2][1] then I get an exception, but the html changes so It needs to cope with null dor non existant arrays elements

```
    //first line
    textBlock1.Text = node[0][0];
    textBlock2.Text = node[0][1];
    textBlock3.Text = node[0][2];

    //first line
    textBlock4.Text = node[1][0];
    textBlock5.Text = node[1][1];
    textBlock6.Text = node[1][2];

    //first line
    textBlock7.Text = node[2][0];
    textBlock8.Text = node[2][1];
    textBlock9.Text = node[2][2];
```

Array is from this code:

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var html = e.Result;

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    var list = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").ToList();

    var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "departures")
        .Element("tbody")
         .Elements("tr")
          .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray())
          .ToArray();
```

Comment: Is this a multidimensional array or a jagged array? You imply that it's multidimensional, but in that case if [2][1] is not valid it means that *all* of the third row or the second column will not be valid.

Comment: Can you add some more code? I can't tell from the code you've posted it's an array - can be just types with indexers

Comment: @jon its a multidimensional array. The array size is based on HTML parse, os sometimes all the rows are not valid and thats what I want to error check. Check if the array exists before binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check length for both dimensions, e.g.

```
if (node.Length > 2)
{
   //first line
   if (node[2].Length > 0)
   {
      textBlock7.Text = node[2][0];
   }
}
```

Comment: Using a conditional? Or how would I implement?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it wont let me use node[0] as it is an [][] array.

Comment: I've edited again :-) What is the exact type of node? is it really multidimensional array, or just some type with indexers?

Comment: Thanks for your help. but still not working, error: operator && cannot be applied to Bool or int. The array is a combination. It is a list of the 3 values, each line has three values. PLacename, number, number.

Comment: Ok, it is an multi-dimensional array :-) fixed my code last time, next time I should be using compiler :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3481/discussion-between-amittai-shapira-and-rhys)